# Understanding usage of array syntax in jquery buildfragment

Tags: jquery

I was just going through the jQuery defragment method and came across the following line of code:

```
tag = (rtagName.exec(elem) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase();
```

What is this line of code really doing? Can somebody explain? Starting from left to right, I see a variable assignment, the exec method used, the `||` operator used and then the confusing part , what is the `[["", ""]]` , what on earth is this for?

I have gone through the jQuery source a few times and also read a couple of articles online.

1. [DOM manupulation](http://dailyjs.com/2011/03/10/framework-53/) .
2. [jQuery defragment](http://www.blog.highub.com/javascript/decoding-jquery-dommanip-dom-manipulation/)

but I still don't get this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.exec()` is a regular expression method:

> The exec() method executes a search for a match in a specified string. Returns a result array, or null.

**Here is how the `||` works**:

The result returned by this method is either an array or `null`. If an array is returned then the `["", ""]` part is *discarded* and the resulting array is used for the rest of the expression. Otherwise the resulting `null` is *discarded* and  `["", ""]` is used for the rest of the expression.

For example, let's say `rtagName.exec(elem)` returned:

```
["we", "Quir", "idid"]
```

Then the result of the expression would be:

```
(["we", "Quir", "idid"] || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase()

(["we", "Quir", "idid"])[1].toLowerCase()

"Quir".toLowerCase()

"quir"    //final result
```

Otherwise the final result would be "":

```
(null || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase()

(["",""])[1].toLowerCase()

"".toLowerCase()

""    //final result
```

And here is the equivalent in plain terms:

```
var x = rtagName.exec(elem);
var tag;
if( x ) {
    tag = x[1].toLowerCase();
} else {
    tag = "";
}
```

Without `|| ["",""]` there's a chance that you'll end up with `(null)[1].toLowerCase()` which would throw an error, which would cause your code to fail. 
Since the `.exec()` method is primarily concerned with searching a string for a match, you either find a match or you don't; `["", ""]` enables you to return "" (empty string) -- instead of throwing an error -- when no match is found.

Comment: OMG !! thats not what i was asking !

Comment: discard the explanation for exec in the answer and explain what `["", ""]` is doing there ?

Comment: It's a smart way of condensing a series of several lines of code that would definitely include at least an if statement into one line. Take the above explanation and try to write the code that would achieve that. Let me know if I should clarify anything.

Comment: thanks maybe ur answer might be hepful to someone looking this up later , i totally understand that part before i posted , my question is why not `tag = (rtagName.exec(elem))[1].toLowerCase();` instead of `tag = (rtagName.exec(elem) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase();` ?

Comment: I totally understand your concern. Without `|| ["",""]` there's a chance that you'll end up with `(null)[1].toLowerCase()` which would throw an error, which would cause your code to fail. Since the `.exec()` method is primarily concerned with searching a string a match, you either find a match or you don't; `["", ""]` enables you to return `""` (empty string) -- instead of throwing an error -- when no match is found.

Comment: Wow thanks fantastic , add that part to your answer Pls and i'll accept your answer !